# Can I turn off an Apache Directive then turn it on in an include?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, apache-config

I have a VirtualHost block that includes common configuration items, one directive is ProxyPreserveHost.

Can I "procedurally" turn off ProxyPreserveHost for a Rewrite directive then have the include turn it back on? For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.blah.com
...
...
ProxyPreserveHost off
RewriteRule /somepath http://otherhost/otherpath [P]

Include /path/to/file/turning-on-ProxyPreserveHost

</VirtualHost>
```

The otherhost is on a CDN and preserving the host is creating some name resolution issue that is not allowing the proxying of content in the host namespace.

ProxyReserveHost is only allowed in a Server Config or VirtualHost. It doesn't look like I can selectively turn it off for the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives (encapsulated in the proxy flag of mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following, found on the internet, addressed my dilemma. As an aside, there is an open feature request to make `ProxyPreserveHost` configurable at the Location and Directory level within the Apache HTTPD project.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <Proxy "http://${build.replace.host}/">
    RequestHeader set Host ${build.replace.external.host}
  </Proxy>
  RewriteRule      ^/proxypath/ http://${build.replace.external.host}/path/to/resource.html [P]
  ProxyPassReverse /proxypath/ http://${build.replace.external.host}/path/to/resource.html
</IfModule>
```