# ProxyPreserveHost On for one reverse proxy only?

Tags: apache, proxy, httpd.conf

We use a third-party server that does not appear to handle comma-delimited X-FORWARDED-HOST values properly. In summary, it generates HTML pages containing invalid URLs like `http://externalsite_address, internalsite_address/blah/blah/blah` when it is reached through proxies (this scenario is described in more detail at: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/66787-Multiple-Reverse-Proxies?p=306157). Organizationally, we have no choice but to use this third-party server and it's not open source, so we can't fix anything ourselves. I have been trying for two weeks to overcome this problem but, given our organization's web architecture, still can't get things to work as desired. What we would like to see in those HTMLs' URLs is `http://externalsite_address/blah/blah/blah`.

In a test environment, I have learned that I can get things to work as desired by setting ProxyPreserveHost On for the server acting as the external site and then on the internal site add the directive "RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-Host". Everything works fine doing this. Unfortunately, the real external site's configuration is a proxy server for all the other servers in our organization and we've been refused permission to introduce a server configuration change like this because it may impact other applications that exist on other internal servers in the organization.

In looking at the documentation for ProxyPreserveHost, I find that it can also be set within the context of a VirtualHost. However, I'm not sure how to define something like that in this case. All web traffic into our organization has to be routed through this externalsite_address and there is only a single RewriteRule that forwards appropriate traffic to our specific internalsite_address through a proxy, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/atlas(.*)$ http://internalsite_address/atlas$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

Is there some way I can define that as a VirtualHost with the ProxyPreserveHost On within it? Everything I've read thus far suggests that a VirtualHost needs a different address or port and couldn't be used with the same address as the organization's. That is, we still need people to reach our internal server via `http://externalsite_address/atlas`, so I don't think setting up a VirtualHost is an option here...am I correct or just misunderstanding the documentation?

Assuming that I can't use the ProxyPreserveHost directive because it is only valid within the server configuration or a VirtualHost, I've been trying to figure out some way to accomplish this on our internal server only. I found [Can I turn off an Apache Directive then turn it on in an include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427874/can-i-turn-off-an-apache-directive-then-turn-it-on-in-an-include) which suggested this code:

```
<Proxy "http://${build.replace.host}/">
  RequestHeader set Host ${build.replace.external.host}
</Proxy>
RewriteRule      ^/proxypath/ http://${build.replace.external.host}/path/to/resource.html [P]
ProxyPassReverse /proxypath/ http://${build.replace.external.host}/path/to/resource.html
```

However, I couldn't figure out how I could set the Host value properly because, while external users must come through our externalsite_address, our internal users can, do and must continue to be able to come directly through our internalsite_address. So, sometimes that Host value should say `http://externalsite_address/` and other times `http://internalsite_address/`. Really, what I would like to be able to do (but have no idea how or if it is even possible) is to somehow determine if the X-FORWARDED-HOST value is set and if so, set the Host in the header to be the first value listed in the string and then, if necessary, turn on the ProxyPreserveHost so that value is maintained through subsequent proxies.

Another way I found of solving this is to introduce another proxy definition on our external server that goes directly to the third-party server given a particular URL as follows (note the "rest" after "atlas", which is always there for requests that are ultimately handled by that server):

```
RewriteRule ^/atlas/rest/(.*)$ http://internalsite_address/atlas/rest/$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

Unfortunately, doing this would require poking a hole through a firewall into another zone of the system architecture and that has also been refused. The external server can proxy to our internal server (which is in the same zone) and our internal server (which is not directly visible externally) is the only one that has all the permissions defined to allow requests to get at all the other servers that are used to deliver web applications which exist in another zone. Please don't ask me to justify any of this, the architecture was dictated to us and we're just trying to figure out how to work within it.

Can anyone suggest anything that will help me achieve what I am trying to accomplish here? Even something I haven't found yet? Or, alternatively, is there some way that I can define a VirtualHost on the external server so I can set the ProxyPreserveHost flag on for only those requests that are routed to our internal server?

Really, at this point, I'd appreciate just about any clues...

Cheers,
jtm

Comment: Did you ever come to a solution to this issue?